# Jenkins PHP Template - Display's loading message and blocks UI

Tags: php, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-php

I'm trying to use the template from http://jenkins-php.org in my installation of Jenkins. As soon as I go in to configure the project I get a grey screen appearing and the words 'Loading'

[image: Jenkins & PHP-Template - Stuck on Loading]

If I look in the Browser error console I get `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'registry.get')`

Has anyone else experienced this problem? How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had this problem when upgraded to 1.528.

Digging further, we found out that the problem is originated from one of the client-side script files called "***hudson-behavior.js***" and is caused by the "**Publish Over SSH**" plugin. There have been other plugins that have caused this in the past, as well. We couldn't disable the plugin anyway. So we searched further.

Long story short, we ended up changing the script for the time being. If you, like us, install Jenkins using the war file, then the script file is probably extracted and cached in "*/var/cache/jenkins/war/scripts/hudson-behavior.js*".

The following change we made was in a function called "***registerValidator***":

```
        if (depends==null) { // legacy behaviour where checkUrl is a JavaScript

           try {
              return eval(url); // need access to 'this', so no 'geval'
           } catch (e) {
              // set depends to an empty array.
              depends = [];
           }
        }

        var q = qs(this).addThis();
```

The URL may not always be valid. Thus, a try-catch is in order. Hope this helps!

Comment: The function has changed since this was published.

Answer (score 2):

I've just had the same issue, I'm using version 1.523 of Jenkins on an Ubuntu server.

The solution I found was to manually edit the project `config.xml` file.

`sudo vim /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/yourProjectName/config.xml`

- I had images in the description and I removed those leaving the description tag empty.
- I also had an empty plot section which I removed completely from the publishers section.

After saving the config and going back to 'manage Jenkins' and then 'Reload Configuration from Disk' I then reopend my project and the config opened normally again.

I wasn't getting quite the same error message as you in the browser console to start with, but I hope that helps.

Comment: same on 1.522 and 1.525.

This should be resolved right now but it's not.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18674

Comment: Same issue 1.528 - I can't just "disable all plugins" and risk my settings all blowing up... frustrating.

Comment: I downgraded from 1.528 and 1.523 and it worked for me - I manually deleted the WAR expanded directory as well and had the problem with 1.528 - looks like a race condition considering all the different JS errors people are reporting.

Answer (score 0):

I too downgraded to 1.523 and then it worked... So it's obviously some bug introduced after 1.524.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from 1.530 to 1.531 fixed it for me.